# How can you know when user scroll to next widget in list flutter (widget before not visible anymore)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ScrollablePositionedList and want to do stuff when the next Widget in the List is scrolled to. How can I detect that? I have tried with NotificationListener and  ScrollUpdateNotification but only saw the option to use the height of each widget which is flexible and it would be kinda ugly to do it like this. Is there a better way? Like see the pixel height of a widget or is there a function I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to monitor what items are visible on screen with:

```
itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.addListener(() => ...);
```

Then, based on this. you can see whenever there is a change, whenever a new item is scrolled to / appears in the list. then make whatever changes you want

[Here is the documentation for more info](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)